# quiero alterar un diccionario, pero simultáneamente necesito hacer un bucle con las llaves de este diccionario,

Tags: python, bucles, diccionarios

Pues logré solucionar el problema volviendo las llaves del diccionario en una lista, pero ¿no hay una forma que no requiera hacer el bucle sobre otra variable? El error que me sale es que estoy modificando el diccionario,
gracias

Comment: Bienvenido PABLO ARIZA a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Por favor, comparte el código de lo que estas haciendo.

Answer (score 0):

Podes encontrar las llaves del diccionario con el `.keys()` metodo:

```
# ejemplo
d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}

# llaves a lista
lista = list(d.keys())

print(lista)
["a", "b", "c"]
```